# Gnome: Keyboard shortcut to move to workspace 7 (or higher)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces, dconf

In Gnome I can have a fixed number of workspaces. As I have ten number keys, I have created ten workspaces. So I want <kbd>Super+1</kbd> to switch to workspace 1, <kbd>Super+2</kbd> to switch to workspace 2 and so on. I can acchieve this by running the following command for each workspace:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Super>1']"
```

This works for all 10 workspaces.

Now, similar, I want to assign <kbd>Super+Shift+1</kbd> to move the current window to workspace 1. So I tried the following command for each workspace:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/move-to-workspace-1 "['<Shift><Super>exclam']"
```

This works fine for workspaces 1-6. Starting with workspace 7, <kbd>Super+Shift+7</kbd> or `<Shift><Super>slash` (German keyboard) does not trigger anything - though if I assign it to another action the keyboard shortcut works.

How can I enable the `move-to-workspace` keyboard shortcuts for workspaces with numbers greater than 6?

Comment: FTR: it actually works nowadays, tested on Gnome 40.2. I.e. you can assign the bindings for workspaces higher than 7 the way you do this *(tested with 7 and 8)*, and it works, it moves windows there as expected.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a new custom shortcut

  [image: GNOME - New shortcut]
- Use [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdotool.1.html). In the command line put "xdotool getactivewindow set_desktop_for_window **8**" to send your window on the workspace **9** (there is a -1 delta to take into consideration with xdotool).

  [image: GNOME - Setting the command called by the shorcut]
- This sends the window to the desired workspace but doesn't switch the view to it. Personally, I prefer to have another shortcut to move to the workspace (xdotool set_desktop 8).

Hope this help!

Comment: I presume, this is not gonna work on Wayland, which is why it's important to note that the standard way author was trying to do that should work nowadays. That is,in my tests, binding a shortcut to move a window to desktops 7 and 8 works fine. Tested on Gnome 40.2.